# How to ensure disk flushes properly when writing many files quickly in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, node.js, macos, unix, ubuntu

I create many files in my node.js script.

I do something like this for millions of files:

```
    if(!fs.existsSync(path)){
        var empty = {};
        fs.writeFileSync(path,JSON.stringify(empty,null,3));
    }

    var data = fs.readFileSync(path);
    var file = JSON.parse(data);
    file[aKey] = "someadata";
    fs.unlinkSync(path);
    fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(file,null,3));
```

And in some places I try to read the files

```
    if(!fs.existsSync(previousPath)){
        var file = {};
        fs.writeFileSync(previousPath,JSON.stringify(file,null,3));
    }
    var data = fs.readFileSync(previousPath);
```

This works without a problem on OSX. But on the version of node in Ubuntu, it seems that the synchronous methods, aren't always synchronous - sometimes node.js crashes when trying to readFileSync, saying that the path doesn't exist (even though it should exist, since I call fs.writeFileSync on it just before).

version of node on ubuntu: v0.10.33
on mac :  v0.13.0-pre

Any suggestions ? v0.10.33 seems to be the latest in the repository in ubuntu.

Comment: Why not use the async versions ? As far as I know, they are the recommended ones.

Comment: This is a bit unrelated, but why unlink the file at `path` if you're writing to the same `path` on the next line? `fs.writeFileSync()` will just overwrite the file, so there is no need to `fs.unlink()` beforehand. Similarly, why read the file you just wrote?

Comment: @nha I use sync, because I need to create the file system in a determinable manner, since I need to update files repeatedly.

Comment: @mscdex I left out some code in the example above to make it less verbose. The actual program does some things to update the data, which I omitted here, since the point is I need to update the file fairly soon after and cannot use the async version since it could result in inconsistent data.